# MySQL - Creating a Stored Procedure with multiple parameters

Tags: mysql

I already have a table set up as follows:

```
mysql> describe schedules;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Email   | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Lunch   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Classes | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Labs    | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I then tried to create a stored procedure for the schedule as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE updateSchedule(IN @email VARCHAR(255),
IN @lunch INT,
IN @schedule TEXT,
IN @labs TEXT)
BEGIN
REPLACE INTO schedules VALUES (@email, @lunch, @schedule, @labs);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

which resulted in this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near '@email varchar(255),
      IN @lunch INT,
      IN @schedule TEXT,
      IN @labs TEXT)
      BEGIN
      REPL' at line 2
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try removing `@` character from variables.

Comment: Works. Thank you.